# Is there such thing as a 'hyperphrase'?

Tags: phrases, hypernyms, hyponyms

In linguistics there is a common hierarchy of words:

```
Hypernym     (e.g. Colours)    
   |
   V
Hyponym     (e.g. Brown, yellow)
```

Does such a hierarchy exist within phrases?

Comment: Hypernym: *electromagnetic radiation*, hyponym: *infra-red, visible light, ultraviolet,* etc.

Comment: http://linqs.cs.umd.edu/basilic/web/Publications/2015/grycner:emnlp15/agrycner-emnlp15.pdf

Comment: There is a hierarchy of concepts. If a concept does not have a single word to describe it, then maybe the corresponding phrase is in hyper or hypo relations to others. This probably more likely to get an good answer at http://linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Three other members of the ELU community also feel that this is principally a linguistics question, rather than specific to English. Unfortunately it's too old to migrate there.

Comment: I can see your thinking; can we get a mod to come and migrate it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as is mentioned above, it is primarily a question for [Linguistics.se].

Answer (score 0):

There are papers analyzing the hierarchy of phrases. [For example this one](http://ijcai.org/Proceedings/87-1/Papers/024.pdf), or [the one Lambie mentioned in the comments](http://linqs.cs.umd.edu/basilic/web/Publications/2015/grycner:emnlp15/agrycner-emnlp15.pdf). That suggests that in linguistic research there are phrases like *specialized phrase* and *generalized phrase* and they do appear in literature as [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=specialized+phrase%2C+generalized+phrase&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspecialized%20phrase%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgeneralized%20phrase%3B%2Cc0) shows.

Thus, a hierarchy exists and can be described by using *specialized* and *generalized*. I don't know if there is a way to describe more levels properly.

Comment: So, a generalised phrase -> hypernym and specialised -> hyponym? Vaguely speaking.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey vaguely speaking that seems to be the case.